# why do some pseudo-elements seem like pseudo-classes?

Tags: css

pseudo-elements are like virtual elements, however it seems to me that many of them are more like classes than elements.

eg. ::PLACEHOLDER ::SELECTION ::FIRST-LINE ::FIRST-LETTER ::BACKDROP

Can someone explain to me how these are considered elements and not classes? They aren't creating any new elements, they are just applying a class in certain circumstances.

Comment: You couldn't use google for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: @Pete, nothing on that page answers my question

Comment: How about : *pseudo-elements are added to selectors but instead of describing a special state, they allow you to style certain parts of an element* and if you follow the link to pseudo classes: *A CSS pseudo-class is a keyword added to selectors that specifies a special state of the element to be selected.*

Comment: yes, that is more like the clarification I was after.

Comment: It seems to me that the key difference is that pseudo-elements affect parts of elements, as opposed to whole elements, and that isn't clear from the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo-classes target an existing element when the state of it matches a condition.

You can target `a` and `a:visited` and they will match exactly the same "thing" when it is in the visited state.

Pseudo-elements target something that isn't an element in its own right. The `:first-line` of an element isn't event a complete DOM node.

Comment: what about backdrop?

Comment: @FrazerKirkman — From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop) — *This pseudo-element is a box rendered immediately below the element* — So it's something entirely new, like `::before`.